# Xamarin.forms:WebView scale did not wwork

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my app there is a webview .I have set the scale in iOS custom renderer.I can zoom the webview before it finishload.But it doen't when it finishload.

> in webview renderer

```
WebView.LoadFinished += LoadFinished;

//...

private void LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var contentSize = WebView.ScrollView.ContentSize;
    var viewSize = View.Bounds.Size;
    var scale = viewSize.Width / contentSize.Width;

    WebView.ScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = scale*0.5 ;
    WebView.ScrollView.MaximumZoomScale = scale*2 ;
}
```

Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

Because you didn't refer to the tag meta in your html file.

**Solution:**

Add the following code in the method LoadFinished

```
private void LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //. . .

    NSString str = new NSString("var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=2.0';meta.name='viewport';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);");
    webView.EvaluateJavascript(str); 
}
```

> minimum-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=2.0

You can set the value of MinimumZoomScale and MaximumZoomScale here.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will tell you result whether it is useful or not

Comment: Hey,I use the url("https://www.google.com") and it works.However,when use my own url some times it doesn't.I think your answer is right,but can you   explain it to me?

Comment: Can you provide the code of your html file .And,what  is the mean of some times?